# Kendo React basic Form submit

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I've created a basic Kendo React Form, but nothing happens when I hit 'Submit'.
Why doesn't the alert get called?

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Field, Form, FormElement } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";

const handleSubmit1 = (dataItem) => {
  alert(1);
};

const AppComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit1}
   
      render={(formRenderProps) => (
        <FormElement>
          <button type={"submit"} disabled={false}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </FormElement>
      )}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.querySelector("my-app"));
```

Working example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/black-currying-459p5h?file=/app/main.jsx

Comment: Did you provide the KendoReact licence key?

Comment: @Spikatrix only needed in Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some input fields to your form for the user to enter data. Without any fields, the form won't have anything to submit, and your `handleSubmit` function won't be called. Just add some Field components to your Form.

##### Example:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Field, Form, FormElement } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";

const handleSubmit1 = (dataItem) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(dataItem));
};

const AppComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit1}
      render={(formRenderProps) => (
        <FormElement>
           // component attribute on <Field/> is mandatory! 
          <Field name="firstName" label="First name" component="input" />
          <button type="submit" disabled={!formRenderProps.allowSubmit}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </FormElement>
      )}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.querySelector("#my-app"));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you.  It seems a weird requirement